# Command block not telling the right player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure map in 1.13.2, where a player would step out of spawn and then a tellraw would trigger, a sort of welcome message. My original problem was the command to use, but a quick Google search took care of that.

Now I have my full command, in a single command block set to always run:

```
/execute if entity @a[x=1234,y=22,z=-244] run tellraw @a[x=1234,y=22,z=-244] ["",{"text":"<"},{"text":"?????","color":"dark_red"},{"text":"> "},{"text":"Well well well, you've woken up. Only took you 2 hours.","color":"dark_red"}]
```

It looks fine, but it doesn't run when a player is at the specified location. Instead it runs when a block update occurs to or near it, giving the message to the nearest player.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try:

```
execute as @a[x=1234,y=22,z=-244,dx=1234,dy=22,dz=-244] run tellraw @s ["",{"text":"<"},{"text":"?????","color":"dark_red"},{"text":"> "},{"text":"Well well well, you've woken up. Only took you 2 hours.","color":"dark_red"}]
```

Since it doesn't seem to be working but we've determined the command is NOT the problem, here are some things that might help debug it. I've thought of a lot of things that could be a factor:

-Make sure your chat is activated.
-Make sure there's no lag. Type something in the chat and see if it pops up.
-Make sure the command block is functioning properly. Copy the command, destroy the block and place a new one.
-Make sure the command block is being powered.
-Teleport yourself to the coordinates in the command and see if that helps.

If all that fails, you could try another method:

```
execute as @a[distance=..0.5] positioned 1234 22 -244 run tellraw @s ["",{"text":"<"},{"text":"?????","color":"dark_red"},{"text":"> "},{"text":"Well well well, you've woken up. Only took you 2 hours.","color":"dark_red"}]
```

If that doesn't work then I have no idea what it is. Sorry.

Comment: Also not working. The text is fine, as I said, the message would correctly send when a block update occurred.

Comment: And you're at the exact spot as the coordinates indicated in the the execute's brackets?

Comment: Yes, I am. It's still not giving the message.

Comment: I edited the answer above and tested it, it should definitely work. If it doesn't work, double check you're at the right coordinates and make sure your command block is functioning. Other than that I'm not sure what could be the problem. EDIT: You could also try adding distance=..1,

Comment: Again, it's not working. Everything seems to be correct, but it doesn't run.

Comment: How far away is the command block that's running it? Are you going so far the chunk deloads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87310/discussion-between-dragonslayr15001-and-spiceweasel).